# Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

im trying to use pay paypal sdk in laravel 4 then it shows an error like this "Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found in laravel 4"

Comment: Where's the code you're using? Have you included the necessary dependencies in composer?

Comment: Make sure your paypal SDK is included in ```composer.json``` file and you run ```composer update``` or ```composer dump-autoload```

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't included the requirements in your composer.json or in your service-providers. Maybe that helps:

http://jslim.net/blog/2014/09/19/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4/

Comment: What should the service providers be?